# How to perform crossvalidation using SVM polynomial?

Tags: classification, matlab

I am using an SVM polynomial kernel (`statistics toolbox`) with order ranging (say) from 3 to 9. When we perform cross validation with `rbf` function, we intend to determine the sigma and C values. With the best sigma and cost factor value, the trained network is tested on the test set. Do we determine cost function and sigma as well while performing cross-validation using SVM polynomial kernel? The commands that I intend to use are

```
structtr = svmtrain(z1, trainoutput, 'Kernel_Function', 'Polynomial', 'Polyorder', i,
                    'showplot', false);
grouparousallat = svmclassify(structtr, w1, 'showplot', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a RBF kernel you use crossvalidation to determine the best {C;sigma} pair (where `C` is the regularization/cost parameter and `sigma` is the standard deviation/shape parameter for your kernel).
However, with a polynomial RBF you don't have a `sigma` since you don't have a Gaussian (or Gaussian-like) kernel (shape).
For the polynomial kernel you might want to determine the best {C;d} pair (where `d` is the degree of your polynomial).

Comment: You could perhaps also consider CV over alternative choices of $\kappa$ constant in $(\kappa+x^Tx^\prime)^d$